# AWS Elastic Beanstalk 502 bad gateway on Get method

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I try to implement Facebook authentification on my web application but I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway error when my nodejs server try to send a response throw `facebook/auth/callback` request.

Here my request logs :

[image]

My nodejs server is deployed on `elastic beanstalk` and uses `nginx` proxy.

I read this error can occurs when response's is too big. So I tried to edit this size using the following code :

01buffer_proxy.con :

```
files:
"/etc/nginx/conf.d/app_proxy_buffer.conf" :
     mode: "000644"
     content: |
server {
location / {
    proxy_buffering      on;
    proxy_buffer_size    16k;
    proxy_buffers        32   16k;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;

container_commands:
    01_reload_nginx:
    command: "service nginx reload"
 }
```

But I still get the error.

Do you think it's a response's size problem ? If yes, how edit proxy buffer size on `elastic beanstalk`.

Thanks.

Comment: Which port you are using? Can you try with port 5000